# etc/apt/sources.list contents for EC2 Instances upon AWS

Tags: ubuntu, apt, amazon-ec2, aws

When I copy an Ubuntu image between regions, the image is customised slightly in the process. Notably the software sources in /etc/apt/sources.list are altered to "local values".

I am aware that these are not mirrors, the package "manifests" are not even guaranteed to be the same between regions.

Are these differences documented anywhere ? Reasons could include DCMA or compliance ?  Are some packages customised as well for AWS ?

Comment: This sounds like it *could* be something done by cloud-init: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit

Comment: Yes, there is a comment block to this effect at the head of sources.list, and a statement that modifications will not survive a "re-bundle".  But who decides what packages are omitted from the repositories ?  I can add internet "universe" mirrors and and install wput say, and that will persist in a new ami cut from a snapshot, but will never be updated unless I  set apt_preserve_sources_list to true and restrict updates to particular packages.

Comment: afaik, "who decides" is Ubuntu/Canonical.  The images for Ubuntu on EC2 are "official" images. http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases

Comment: OK, so Canonical then. The key word from that page is "customized", some of those pages date back to Maverick times. I am aware of it at least more acutely now. Odd that Oregon should differ from Sydney though, since they both "official".